# video posting to server through http post method in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, post

Please fine my code that i wrote to post a video to server using HTTP post method.

The server is being hit but the response is showing null I don't understand what would have gone wrong

```
 - (IBAction)choose:(id)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}



      - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


  if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] ||

    [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])

   {


    self.videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

}

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

 - (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {

    //NSString * str = @"content";

  //    [str stringByAppendingString:self.url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://mobile.supportservice.co.in/bbgapp.asmx/Stream" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    //NSString * str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"amyVideo" ofType:@"png"];

    NSLog(@"------------------>%@",self.videoURL);


    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoURL] name:@"file" fileName:@"myVideo.m4v" mimeType:@"mp4/m4v" error:nil];

} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;

uploadTask = [manager

              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request

              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

                  // This is not called back on the main queue.

                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                      //Update the progress view

                      [self.progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];

                  });

              }

              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                  if (error) {

                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

                  } else {


  NSLog(@"----------------------> %@ %@", response, responseObject);

                  }

              }];

[uploadTask resume];
}
  @end
```

Here is my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jogex.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to upload/download video or image use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework. For upload Video use below code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
URLString:@"http://exampleurl.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
 [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view
                      [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```